# Media player in C++

Tags: c++, c, media-player, ogg-theora

I have the following issues when trying to compile the [libtheoraplayer](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/libtheoraplayer/index.php?title=Main_Page) demo (av_player demo).

If someone can help me out with some errors from libtheoraplayer ([image: errors while compiling av_player demo]), I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with linux then check the vlc source code it is free 
but it is C  code.

it may be help to you.

Thanks.

Comment: VLC works on Windows as well, so does mplayer. Both are open source.

Answer (score 0):

LINK2019 means: this project invoke some function (such as CreateContext) but msvc just find this function declaration and no implement. it happend when project dont link the lib of this function .so you need to find the lib of those functions . And "#parama commect(lib, libname.lib"   .